# Swi-prolog breaks on order check

Tags: prolog

I have the following code on Prolog

```
concat([], [], []).
concat([], [H|T], [H|T2]) :- concat([], T, T2).
concat([H|T], L2, [H|T2]) :- concat(T, L2, T2).

is_ordered([]).
is_ordered([_X]).
is_ordered([X,Y|Tail]) :- X =< Y, is_ordered([Y|Tail]).
```

and I try to get an example of `X` which fit `concat` and `is_ordered`.

When I type

```
concat([1, 2, 3], [4, 4, 4], X)
```

I get result, but when I try to do the same with `is_ordered`

```
is_ordered(X)
```

an error occurs after simple examples `[]` and `[_1784]`

```
{
  "code":500,
  "message":"Unknown error term: assertion_error(fail,pengines:event_term_to_json_data(error('583c29ce-fa49-4b06-971f-1c928260dcac',error(instantiation_error,context(prolog_stack([frame(2,call(system:(=<)/2),_714=<_716),frame(1,pred_line(\"is_ordered/1\",'pengine://583c29ce-fa49-4b06-971f-1c928260dcac/src':31),is_ordered([_756,_762]))]),_676))),_656,'json-html'))"
}
```

Why could this happen?

Comment: What would the rules be, of a *useful* generator? E.g. 1 < 2, 1 < 3, ..., 1 < 9999999, etc. - that is logical, but probably not real-world useful to iterate through into infinity. Are there additional, useful *constraints* to include?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `is_ordered/1` is no constructor, you just can't run it with a not unified variable. Example:

```
?- concat([1, 2, 3], [4, 4, 4], X).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]; 
false.

?- concat([1, 2, 3], [4, 4, 4], X), is_ordered(X).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4];
false.

?- is_ordered(X).
X = [];
X = [_1376];

{
  "code":500,
  "message":"Unknown error term: assertion_error(fail,pengines:event_term_to_json_data(error('05d667b4-a0b8-415b-bee8-459a753f19b3',error(instantiation_error,context(prolog_stack([frame(2,call(system:(=<)/2),_694=<_696),frame(1,pred_line(\"is_ordered/1\",'pengine://05d667b4-a0b8-415b-bee8-459a753f19b3/src':6),is_ordered([_736,_742|_744]))]),_656))),_636,'json-html'))"
}

?- is_ordered([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]).
true;
false.
```

The first example generates your concatenated list `X`. The second query additionally runs the test which you want to apply. The third query on the other hand has no info about the content of the variable and tries to unfy it and will fail while trying to apply the third rule. Tested with SWISH.

So the solution is to run the second query instead of the third.